# System.QueryException: unexpected token: 'FROM'

Tags: apex, soql, debugging

I work on test class so I've to insert `lead` which is related to `parents__c` with lookup field, I created this test apex class (this the first section of the code where I got error).

```
        lead l = new lead();
        list<parents__c> parents = new list<parents__c>();
        try {

            l = new lead(firstname='test',
                         lastname='test',
                         email='test@email.com',
                         company='company',
                         lead_type__c='parent');
            insert l;

            parents = [SELECT Id FROM parents__c WHERE lead__c =: l.Id ];



        } catch(Exception e){
            system.debug('Something went wrong ! '+e + ' lead id = '+l.id );
        }
```

I got this error in debug

```
    Something went wrong !
System.QueryException: unexpected token: 'FROM' lead id = 00Q25000001vCMGEA2
```

Comment: Have you modified your query and then added into Question ? `SELECT Id FROM parents__c WHERE lead__c =: l.Id ` this is correct

Comment: Your api name might be correct, but just a double check...should it be Parent__c instead of Parents__c? As Parents__c would be more correct when you are doing a subquery from lead. Also your reference field - is it Lead_Type__c or Lead__c?

Comment: No, exactly as it ! I saw that no syntax error because of that I submit the question. @Ratan

Comment: @ShaileshDeshpande I checked that, this is the same as API Name, I copied it from the object page.

Comment: Can you check your query in developer console or eclipse. The query syntax seems correct.

Comment: Worth adding `e.getStackTraceString()` to your debug output to be sure its the query you have posted (by checking the line number reported) and not e.g. a query in a Lead insert trigger.

Comment: Oh thanks @KeithC tracing guide me to the main problem which is in the apex class where I want to test. there are a string query with dynamic variable but it ends with , .. thank you all

Comment: @KeithC you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Such error messages indicate that there is a query built using strings and it has a problem.